# How do I connect to db2 using Jupyter Notebook without encountering sql error

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I used the following commands:

```
!pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.9;!pip install ibm_db;!pip install 
      ipython;!pip install ibm_db_sa;!pip install ibm-db;!pip install 
      install ibm-db-sa;import ibm_db

%load_ext sql

# Remember the connection string is of the format:
# %sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@my-hostname:my-port/my-db- 
     name?security=SSL
     # Enter the connection string for your Db2 on cloud database instance 
     below
     %sql ibm_db_sa://.............cloud:3131/Buludb?security=SSL)
```

Then after running the connection I get error either:

> '%sql'is not found

or

> username is not recognized

and other error from creating connecting string.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook in Watson Studio Lite Plan instance and try to connect to Db2 on Cloud.

Comment: Make sure that the cell that loads the SQL magic is executed. Then, make sure that the cell to connect to Db2 on Cloud has the right connection string. Is the database name correct...?

Comment: Hi Henrik , thank you for your response.  The database name is correct as it is copied from ''composed >db2 service credentials".

Comment: Just asking, because in the snippet above it is "Buludb" when it should be "bludb".

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that now, it is my mistake when trying to fix the errors.

Comment: I've sent the connection string I copied. hope it clarify my problem, It was a typo error on my side on the encountered spelling mistake

Comment: db2 -u ............ -p ...... --ssl --sslCAFile 2ce1ab40-7379-45d8-a40c-38dcafaf95d0 --authenticationDatabase admin --host ...................-7217-4024-b027-8baa776ffad1.c3n41cmd0nqnrk39u98g.databases.appdomain.cloud:30875/BLUDB?security=SSL